# FileMaker scheduled script not running

Tags: filemaker

I have a scheduled script that used to run just fine, but no longer is. The schedule is running my open script for the database (and completing it) but isn't even making it to the scheduled script that is supposed to get called.

I am testing by adding a "Freeze Window" step, which creates an error in the server log (incompatible with server). When I add it as the last line in the open script, it gets called and an error gets written to the log. When I add it as the first line in my scheduled script, it never gets called and there is no error in the log.

It looks like this:

Server opens database ->
Runs open script for database, to completion ->
Never runs scheduled script after open script

Any ideas or thoughts? Anyone seen anything like this before?

This is FileMaker Server 15 running on Windows Server.

Comment: Have you checked that the user account you log in with from the server schedule is allowed to run this script? (In Manage security/privilege sets in the database file)

Comment: Good thinking, but yeah it does. I am starting to think this might be a file reference issue. Not sure if server is able to open up external databases and that might be causing issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I am starting to think this might be a file reference issue. Not sure if server is able to open up external databases and that might be causing issue?

FMS Scheduled scripts and PSoS can only work with FM files hosted on the same machine.

> I am testing by adding a "Freeze Window" step, which creates an error in the server log (incompatible with server). When I add it as the last line in the open script, it gets called and an error gets written to the log. When I add it as the first line in my scheduled script, it never gets called and there is no error in the log.

IIRC, FMS will abort the script at the first incompatible step UNLESS Allow User Abort = OFF.

Note also that a Halt step in a subscript will stop the main script too.